# Show file download from flutter application inside Documents folder

Tags: flutter, dart, path-provider

I want to save a text file inside the Documents folder:

I'm saving the file inside "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/" (not using path_provider) but the file isn't shown inside this exact folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yQQL.png)

instaed it is only visible inside the Documents folder inside the Internal Storage folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please be clear on what your purposes are, do you want to store your document in documents folder or download folder? Please try to avoid ambiguity in your questions. That'd be better for each one of us.

Comment: fixed the question for the best for each one of us